# Localization issue in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios4, localization

I need to make an application in which the user can toggle between two languages on triggering a click event on a button.

The problem here is that I have seen examples in which, if we want to load our localized nib file, then we need to change the language from the settings options and we can get the proper nib file loaded according to language selected.

I want to do this within my application, meaning  I don't want to go to the settings menu and change the language and then reload the application.

I just want the above effect within my application (that is, through a button click event the app should be able to toggle between two languages).

Is it possible, and does Apple allow it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody here can tell you whether Apple will allow it, but if your app is well designed and there's a good reason for this departure from the usual way of doing things, you've probably got a good shot.

There's nothing to prevent you from loading a nib file localized for a different region. I'd probably avoid trying to use Apple's automatic mechanism, though. Just name your nib files using some pattern and load the appropriate one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your life to easy, you will take advantage of the Localization built into the operating system.  Otherwise, you will have write your own methods to load localized strings or nib files.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason for Apple to reject an app that shows localized text based on an in-app setting. I work to help developers localize apps and, although I don't suggest this approach, they have done it and I've never heard of a rejection from Apple.

What you won't be able to do is use Apple's built-in tools, which rely on the system settings to determine a user's language and push the text from a Localizable.strings file. But it honestly won't take you too long to implement a similar system yourself using functions akin to [gettext](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/).

You essentially need to implement the same basic logic as any localization system:

1) Surround your in-app texts in a function that will display the proper language based on the user's chosen settings 
2) Export your source texts (probably English into file
3) Translate the English strings into each language in a separate file

The function you write can follow the lines of gettext, which has examples in many programming languages. If the settings is "French" grab the equivalent string from the French file. If the setting is English, just print the English.

You won't be able to use Apple's tools, but you CAN do it on your own and Apple won't really care as far as I know. However, if you choose to localize into an Apple-supported language, follow this [app localization](http://www.ibabbleon.com/iphone_app_localization.html) tutorial for iOS using the standard Localizable.strings method.